# How to send files from Ubuntu 16.04 to iphone 4S?

Tags: 16.04, sync, playonlinux, iphone

I am having a iPhone 4s and a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. I need to copy music, pptx, pdfs from my laptop to iPhone. I read many posts and answers but none of them help me. Even I tried to install iTunes through PlayOnLinux, but it does not allow to sync files between iphone and laptop. As suggested in a answer at askubuntu I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install gvsf-backends
```

then it notifies me that I am having the latest one installed. But when I connect iphone to Ubuntu, only I am able to copy the camera photos ( and other pdfs, pptx...) to my computer only, I cannot copy ones from my computer to the iphone. I even tried Banshee but it does not have "devices" tab in the left side. How to sync music, files and videos from Ubuntu 16.04 to iphone 4s?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution on this page "[How to tranfer files between iPhone and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832350/how-to-tranfer-files-between-iphone-and-ubuntu)" . I have not tried it and cannot confirm if it works or not

Comment: This is best posted as a comment not an answer but you don't have enough rep points to post a comment. Please limit your answers to things you are confident will work.