# How to tranfer files between iPhone and Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, iphone, apple

**How to transfer files between my Ubuntu and iPhone?**

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704669/#704677) recommends to use this URL in nautilus:

```
afc://<your iPhone's UDID>/
```

Then next question is:

**What is my iPhone UDID (without using iTunes)?**

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032162/#21522291) recommends running the following code:

```
lsusb -v 2> /dev/null | grep -e "Apple Inc" -A 2
```

and the result looks like this:

```
iManufacturer           1 Apple Inc.
iProduct                2 iPad
iSerial                 3 7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509...
```

So a URL like this

```
afc://7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509.../
```

Must work in nautilus. While it does not. where am I making mistake?

(`...` are filled with proper part of UDID)

Please do not recommend me to install iTunes on Ubuntu. No matter what method you use either `Wine` or `PlayOnLinux` it cannot work with USB.

Please also consider that the package `gvsf-backends` cannot be located on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` . I am using iPhone 7.

Comment: My smartphone uses Android Marshmallow and no problems with it or previous version Lollipop. This might help you if you have an iPhone 6 though ([http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I am using iPhone 7. Do you recommend anything for that?

Comment: @ar2015 Some or all of the features explored in the linked blog post should work as well for 7. However, you should have realistic expectations. Kudos for dedoimedo for being so honest upfront: *let's no forget that there is NOT going to be any real way you can sync your stuff onto an iPhone 6 without using iTunes. That's an illusion we must destroy right from the beginning.* I couldn't have said it better.

Comment: Your question was a perfect tutorial for me on how to do this and it worked! I did it with a MacBook running Ubuntu 16.04 and an iPhone 7 running iOS 11.1.2.  I had followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/812379/323990) (which also worked BTW) in the past though, so it might affected something.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [Phone Drive](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/phone-drive-file-storage-sync/id431033044) in my Iphone and it worked perfectly!

This works using the browser through a Local Network

I got weird errors using usb...

Answer (score -1):

I use KDE Connect to link my Android phone to my Kubuntu desktop.  In addition to supporting file transfers, it also support transferring the clip board, sharing notifications and using the phone as a mouse control.  It consists of an app on the desktop and an app on the phone.  I don't know if there is an version for the IPhone.