# Iphone 5s cannot be mounted - cannot upload my photos

Tags: mount, iphone, upload

Have been running Ubuntu 12.04 and have been able to mount Iphone 5s and copy and paste photos from the directories on my Iphone 5s and Iphone 4.
My last successful upload on the Iphone 5s was September 24, 2016. Apple's IOS10 may have disabled my ability to mount my Iphone 5s because I can still mount my Iphone4 and examine its directories and access its files.
 Connecting my Iphone 5s to the USB port results in "Unhandled Lockdown error (-5).  I have no idea what that means nor how to clear it.

According to a previous "answer", I tried unpairing and pairing, using:
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
Of course, I then re-connected my Iphone 5s using the USB cable. This did not allow the Iphone to be mounted, had no affect, did not solve the problem, the "Unhandled Lockdown error (-5)" persisted.
    Some "answers" have suggested using libimobiledevice from libimobiledevice.org for accessing the directories on my Iphone 5s, but others have related problems with libimobiledevice and an askubuntu.com moderator questioned why the troubled user installed it in the first place.
Tried having Iphone plugged in upon boot - no help
I can mount my Iphone 5s running IOS 10 on my Windows-based tablet and copy files, but can no longer do this on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.
I can still mount my Iphone 4 running IOS 7.2.1 on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: See if this answer helps out: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/832350/how-to-tranfer-files-between-iphone-and-ubuntu/832519?noredirect=1#comment1270203_832519]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add clarity. What did you try? What happened when you did? Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide the output of `uname -r` please

Comment: uname -r "3.2.0-113-generic"